# como utilizo setContentView para una instancia de ZBarScanner en un fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, qrcode

En una app que hice, sobre un lector qr, en el archivo MainActivity.java corre normal el 1er bloque de codigo mostrado en onCreate().
Ahora en el bloque de código sgte. en onCreateView() implemente en un fragment, y no encuentro el código que reemplace a .setContentView(). gracias

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnEscanear = findViewById(R.id.btnEscanear);
    etCodigoEscaneado = findViewById(R.id.etCodigoEscaneado);
    btnEscanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Overrid
    public void onClick(View v) {
    vistaEscaner = new ZBarScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    vistaEscaner.setResultHandler(new zbarScanner());
    setContentView(vistaEscaner);
    etCodigoEscaneado.setText("Escaneando...");
    vistaEscaner.startCamera();
    }
  });
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lector_qr, container, false);
  btnEscanear=vista.findViewById(R.id.btnEscanear);
  btnEscanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onclick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    vistaEscaner = new ZBarScannerView(getContext());// Inicializar programáticamente la vista del escáner
    vistaEscaner.setResultHandler(new zbarScannerr());// Regístrese como un controlador para los resultados del análisis.
    ViewGroup contentFrame = vista.findViewById(R.id.content_main);
    contentFrame.addView(vistaEscaner);// Establecer la vista del escáner como la vista de contenido
    vistaEscaner.startCamera();// Iniciar la cámara en el currículum
    }
  });
  return vista;
}
```

Comment: creo que lo que buscas es esto : inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuLayout, container, false);

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo gracias. Ahora Ya logro capturar el codigo qr.. pero no se cierra la camara con stopCamera()..se queda congelada.. esta en un fragmento en un RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Para cerrar la cámara lo recomendable es seguir estos pasos:

```
//Supongo qur tienes un método que sea handleResult o algo parecido
@Override
public void handleResult(final Result result)
{
   //Haces lo que necesitas con los resultado.
   vistaEscaner.removeAllViews(); //Esto limpiará las vies de la actividad que estes usando.
   vistaEscaner.stopCamera(); //Esto parará la cámara
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Vuelves a cargar la vista
}
```

Con esto mte devería de funcionar.

Comment: Me ayudo, solo que yo lo hago en fragments.. y algunas cosas cambian.. pero gracias.